# Subnormal subgroups of a subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Then if $K \triangleleft \triangleleft \,G$, and $K \leq H$, it is clear that $K \triangleleft \triangleleft \,H$. I want to find out if the subnormal subgroups of $H$ are exactly those subnormal subgroups of $G$ contained in $H$?

Comment: E.g. subgroup $H$ is a normal subgroup of $H$ itself, but does not have to be a normal subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not generally true, as you've noted the set of subnormal subgroups of $G$ contained in $H$ is contained in the set of subnormal subgroups of $H$, but the converse inclusion does not hold.

To find a large number of counterexamples consider any non-abelian simple group, $A_n$ with $n\ge 5$ for example. These have only two subnormal subgroups - themselves and the the trivial group. Any proper non-trivial subgroup $H$ of $A_n$ is subnormal in itself but certainly not in $A_n$. Some subgroups, $H=A_4$ for example contain proper normal (and therefore subnormal) subgroups which are not subnormal in $A_n$.